# How to show all records with multiple one to many and a many to many relationship with php pdo?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to show all of my doctors record with its relationship with other tables, but only one record from those relationship shows, like from the contacts; it has two contacts but only one shows for the doctor. How may I be able to show all of it?

```
$sql = "SELECT doctors.name, doctors.floor, doctors.room_no, doctors.clinic_address, 
        doctors_schedules.schedule, 
        doctors_contacts.contact_number, doctors_specialties.specialties_id FROM doctors 
        INNER JOIN doctors_schedules ON doctors.id = doctors_schedules.doctor_id
        INNER JOIN doctors_contacts ON doctors.id = doctors_contacts.doctor_id
        INNER JOIN doctors_specialties ON doctors.id = doctors_specialties.doctor_id  
        GROUP BY doctors.id";

        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
```

[image: doctors table]

[image: doctors_contacts]

[image: doctors_schedules]

[image: doctors_specialties]

[image: Result]

Comment: What you're asking for (one to many, many to many, etc) are ideas based on design patterns. PHP PDO is a driver for connecting to a database. These are mutually exclusive ideas. 

If you want to show relationships, you should look into something like Doctrine or Eloquent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use for example DISTINCT and [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat), you can add you own seperatr and order the list

```
$sql = "SELECT doctors.name, doctors.floor, doctors.room_no, doctors.clinic_address, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT doctors_schedules.schedule), 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT doctors_contacts.contact_number),
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT doctors_specialties.specialties_id) 
    FROM doctors 
    INNER JOIN doctors_schedules ON doctors.id = doctors_schedules.doctor_id
    INNER JOIN doctors_contacts ON doctors.id = doctors_contacts.doctor_id
    INNER JOIN doctors_specialties ON doctors.id = doctors_specialties.doctor_id  
    GROUP BY doctors.id";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: sir I already tried the GROUP_CONCAT yesterday but its repeating the values of contacts,schedule and specialties

[GROUP_CONCAT(doctors_specialties.specialties_id)] => 11,10,10,11,9,11,9,10,10,9,11,9 ) 

it looks like this sir

Comment: @antonseverino FWIW, it seems bonkers to me to concatenate data that's then going to be parsed through application code - but whatever floats your boat.